# how can I use a literal # in a python variable or string without it commenting out the rest?

Tags: python, escaping, hashtag

Probably simple but I want to send a post with a color hex in it that the target is expecting but I can't set that value in the color key because it comments out everything after it.

Comment: `#` isn't a comment if it's inside a string.

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with, so we can tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar you're correct. I had it in a string and I tried the post and it worked fine. Nano was just comment coloring everything after it anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `#` as part of the name of a Python variable (see [identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)), but you can put `#` followed by the color code in a string and send it as part of your payload for `POST`ing:

```
var = '#42'
```

Comment: hmm....  the suggestions that were made is exactly how I'm doing it. I haven't tried the post yet because in nano(i know, but I like nano) its already showing it as commented out. Maybe I can just ignore it's colorzing in this case. I will try it and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Yea it worked the way I had it. Thanks for confirming! I guess I shoulda just tried it but I didn't wanna upload anything malformed.